# Twilio - Enqueued call, then dequeued but how do I answer?

Tags: javascript, php, twilio

I'm currently working on a Twilio queuing system but I'm stuck on how to answer the next call in a web browser.

I have all the calls stacking up in the queue and my understanding was that you needed to call Dequeue. But how do I get the browser to connect to this call?

Any help would be great!

Comment: Please add some codes.

Answer (score 2):

Twilio evangelist here.

The easiest way to dequeue a call is to use the `<Dial>` verb with the [`<Queue>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/queue) noun:

```
<Response>
    <Dial>
        <Queue>foo</Queue>
    </Dial>
<Response>
```

This will connect the incoming call to the first call in the Queue.

Its also possible to use the REST API to [redirect a queued call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/member#instance-post).  For example you could redirect the queued call into a conference and then place the incoming client call into that same conference.

Hope that helps.